# Floating inline with a display: block element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to float a div to the right of a bootstrap class (accordion-toggle), but the class has display: block; set, which is why I presume I am having trouble & it won't float inline.

Can someone suggest how I can do this?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
        <div style="float: right;">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KAnVm/)

Edit:
I have achieved the visual effect I am looking for by wrapping the  and my  in another , to which I am applying the accordion-toggle style. The downside to this is that only the  is now active in toggling the accordion, rather than the whole header.

If anybody has a better solution please let me know.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHven/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) add `float:left` to `.accordion-toggle` (you'll need to clear these floats as well by adding `clearfix` class to `.accordion-heading`) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tQUg/), or

b) move the floated `<div />` before `.accordion-toggle`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tQUg/1/)

BTW: `display: inline` has no effect on floating elements (well, except for fixing some IE7 bugs). Floating elements act as if they had `display: block` even if it wasn't explicitly declared.

c) what I think you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/3tQUg/2/

```
.accordion-heading {
       display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.accordion-heading > div {
       display:table-cell;
}
.accordion-heading > a.accordion-toggle {
    display:table-cell;
    width:99%;
}
```

Comment: I tried a & b, but didn't end up with the results I was looking for. With a, the rest of the accordion is affected. b works, but the <div> is not aligned quite right for some reason.

Comment: a) breaks the accordion because floats need to be cleqred (for example add `clearfix` class to `.accordion-heading` (I'll add this info to my answer). Case b) works exactly how floats are supposed to work ;)

Comment: Ah - you're right. The padding comes from accordion-toggle itself, I understand. :-) Thankyou!